# How to test my website in php

Tags: php, windows, web, xampp

I have xampp but dont know how to test my website. the whole site is in C:\brutal doom\web Tester\Phoenix TKD. Do you know how to do this and if so how. Would be helped with pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first coppy your site folder to your c:\xampp\htdocs

then open your xampp control panel and start the first two options

then go to http://localhost/your-site-folder-name-here

and you should see your website

Answer (score 0):

1.First Create a folder in C:\xampp\htdocs\Phoenix
2.Copy your all website data & past to C:\xampp\htdocs\Phoenix folder.
3.Then go to http://127.0.0.1/Phoenix /index.php